# Display blob on JSP

Tags: java, image, spring, jsp, blob

I have class with fields `(string, string, blob)`. On JSP I want to display this obj in table like:

```
<c:forEach var = "p" items="${products}">
 <img src="${p.image}" />
</c:forEach>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: [Should I use tags in the title of my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) No.

Comment: I think you need to covert blob back to Image.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Usually resources referenced in a HTML page are loaded asynchronously, i.e. the browser first loads the HTML page and then loads images etc. referenced in the HTML page. In your case you could write a servlet which delivers the image to the client. In this case the src attribute of the img tag has to contain the path to the servlet.
- The second option is to embed the image Base64 encoded into the src attribute like described in this post: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)